# How to add prefix code on change event dropdown

Tags: codeigniter, dropdown, onchange, prefix

Hi I'm new in codeigniter so this is the problem

I want to add prefix to textbox based on selected value in dropdown menu here's the source

In **Controller**

```
function index(){
    $data['title'] = 'SIPPERTIKOMPPAK|Input Barang';
    $data2 =array(
        'kode_barang' => $this->m_master->kode_barang(),
        'get_lokasi' => $this->m_master->get_lokasi(),
        'get_jenis' => $this->m_master->get_jenis()
    );

    $this->load->view('backend/preload/meta',$data);
    $this->load->view('backend/preload/head');
    $this->load->view('backend/preload/sidebar');
    $this->load->view('backend/master/v_masterb',($data2));
}
```

In **Model**

```
function kode_barang(){
        $kode= $this->db->select_max('id_barang')->get('tb_master_barang')->result_array();
        $qkode = array(); 
        foreach($kode as $r) { 
            $qkode = $r['id_barang']+1; 
        }
        $qkode=str_pad($qkode,3, '0' , STR_PAD_LEFT);
        // $qqkode = 'PRINJ'.$qkode;
        return $qkode;
    }
```

In **View**

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="kode_barang">Kode Barang</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="kode_barang" value="<?php echo $kode_barang; ?>" readonly />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="get_jenis">Jenis Barang</label>
<?php echo form_dropdown('id_jenis', $get_jenis, '', 'class="form-control"');?>
</div>
```

I want to add prefix to textbox for example like this

```
if id_jenis ==1
textbox.value = 'Prefix'+($qkode value from model)
else
textbox.value = 'Prefix'+($qkode value from model)
```

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly your `kode_barang` input field has a value like `stmt` and you want when you change `id_jenis` dropdown for the `kode_barang` input value to change to `prefix stmt`?

Comment: yes something like that for example if I change id_jenis dropdown == 1 then in kode_barang input field will change to PRINJ001 and if I change it to id_jenis == 2 then in kode_barang input field will change to PC001 something like that

Comment: sounds like you want to change the prefix not suffix as your question suggests. where is `PRIN` and `PC` coming from? is that the dropdown item name? further where is `001` coming from?

Comment: Dropdown is list of item group like printer, pc, hdd, LCD, LED, etc and I want in kode_barahg textbox value to change according to the group chosen from dropdown menu for example if user choose PC then in textbox value change to PC001 and 001 come from select max query from one of the table which name is tb_master_barang in the database

Comment: sounds like you'll need ajax as `kode_barang` is dependent/needs to be fetched based on the dropdown. do a simple `onchange` jquery selector.

Comment: I'm new to jquery so I still didn't understand much but Thanks for your suggestions I will try to search more info about your answer